# Apache http server

Tags: apache

I have apache web server with sitemider configuration which is using by weblogic server as backend 
After login to the login page we are getting weblogic thing
Is there is any directive in apache we can add so that after logging out we can come out of login page to the main page

Comment: I mean instead of getting the log out page it should come the main page

Comment: To add information to the question, use the [edit] link.

Comment: Whatever is processin gthe logout (killing session vars, cookies, whatever) needs to redirect to the other URL.  Is it configurable? Is web app you are using Open so you are allowed to change that URL?

Comment: No I am not authorise to do that.. Is there any directive is there in apache we can add